# How can I post my Object via Ajax and store int into the database via Entity Manager?

Tags: ajax, symfony, post, entitymanager

```
$('#form_save').on( 'click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var formData = form.serializeArray();

      alert(formData.toSource());
      $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'{{ path('edit_form', { 'slug': page.slug }) }}',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){

          alert("success");
        }
      });
    });
```

`var formData` is giving me the following alert output:

```
[{name:"form[username]", value:"1"}, {name:"form[email]", value:"1@12.sw"}, {name:"form[is_active]", value:"1"}, {name:"form[plainPassword][first]", value:""}, {name:"form[plainPassword][second]", value:""}, {name:"form[_token]", value:"MdSCmPgzZC3pZaW2wK2Rk"}]
```

How can I use this now into my Controller to store it into the database:

```
public function form($slug, Request $request){

    $id = $request->request->get('id');

    $item = new User();
    $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);

    if($request->request->get('data')){

         $data = $request->request->get('data');
         $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $entityManager->flush();
       }
    }
```

I get the error message:

```
The identifier id is missing for a query of App\Entity\User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery and you are just trying to submit an edit-user form I would initially suggest to use [malsup's ajaxForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). Of course you can implement the same functionality with FormData and ajax request.

In case you use ajaxForm plugin, you just have to set properly your form's action (the route should be something like this: ***/edit-user/1*** where 1 is user's id) and the javascript code will just look like this:

```
$('form#your-form').ajaxForm({
    success: function(response){ alert("success"); }
});
```

The Symfony Controller will look like this:

```
public function form(User $user, Request $request){
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->json('success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `serializeArray` alone for this purpose is pretty useless. In order for it to work, your controller should know the format your are transmitting the data, and by default, Symfony's controller does not expect this format at all.

The best approach is to have your data serialized in a `key:value` format, rather than, `{name: key, value: value}`.

For converting the data, I won't repeat community owned answer: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Once you have your data in `key:value` format, I guess, your could make changes your controller. For example:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

var_dump($data['form[email]']);
```

The above should output the `1@12.sw`. This is a bit clumsy, but it should work. In my opinion, you should really use the Symfony Form component, `submit()` the data to it and use it pretty much ordinarily. The `form[_token]` field suggests that this form's HTML was in fact generated by Symfony Form component, so I do not see the reason for not using it here as well...

Hope this helps...